# is divmod a python builtin function?

Tags: python, keyword

divmod seems to be a builtin as `divmod(5,1)` gives the correct tuple output with no prior imports (at least in Python 3.7.4).

On the other hand

```
import keyword
keyword.kwlist
```

does not list divmod. Also `keyword.iskeyword('divmod')` returns False. Actually even `keyword.iskeyword('int')` and `keyword.iskeyword('hex')` return false. Why is this? What is a keyword and where can we find the complete list of reserved string?

Comment: Reserved words and built-in functions are different things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

divmod is not a keyword, neither is int or hex. These are objects. You can tell by the fact that they are used with parenthesis to call (). Things like in and for and import are keywords.